# How to make a bar plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a file in excel

[image: EXCEL FILE]

I would like to create a plot similar to this in R using the package ggplot.

[image: Desired plot]

I import this excel file into R by 'import dataset from excel'

```
df1<-as.data.frame(GPPNPPMEAN)
> df1
  DATA MEAN  ..3
1 <NA>  GPP  NPP
2   MO 0.45  0.4
3   IP 0.21 0.25
4   MP 0.59 0.24
5   CC 0.62 0.25
```

I do the following

```
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=DATA, y=MEAN, fill=values)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
  geom_text(aes(label=len), vjust=1.6, color="white",
            position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_minimal()
```

Giving an error

> Error: All columns in a tibble must be 1d or 2d objects:
> * Column `fill` is standardGeneric
> Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Is the structure of the dataframe is correct in order to be plotted in gglot? How can I achieve this plot in R?

Answer (score 3):

You should prepare the data in excel like

[image]

Do not provide two headers as you have shown in your question. Then save as the excel file in .csv file and you can read csv using following code

```
df1 <- read.csv("Book1.csv", check.names = F)

df.m <- reshape2::melt(df1)

my_se <- df.m %>%
  group_by(DATA) %>%
  summarise(n=n(),
            sd=sd(value),
            se=sd/sqrt(n))

df.m %>% 
  left_join(my_se) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = DATA, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=DATA, ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se), width=0.4, position = position_dodge(.9))+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
  geom_text(aes(label=len), vjust=1.6, color="white",
            position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_minimal()
```

The code helps you to create the following bar graph. You can change values according to your needs
[image]